# Custom url from hosts file in IntelliJ's GWT DevMode

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

in my hosts file I have

```
127.0.0.1 test.loc.com www.loc.com
```

I'm playing with cookies, create them for different domain names.

In IntelliJ's GWT configuration, in the Dev Mode Parameters I have

```
-startupUrl http://test.loc.com:8888 com.test.MyApp
```

The console output is

```
> Dev Mode initialized. Startup URL: 
> http://test.loc.com:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

I have the "Open in browser" option checked. The browser opens with the url `http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`
and everything looks ok, same with localhost:8888. But when I open

```
http://test.loc.com:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

I get

> Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997

Is that intended? Am I doing it wrong?

Edit: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version is 14.0.1 Trial

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you checked https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM ? (should be linked from the error) Also, have you tried SuperDevMode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That were helpful questions, thanks. It works as expected in Firefox, I was using Chrome. Didn't try SuperDevMode because I want to use the debugger feature.

It's not the first time that the plugin for Firefox works better for me than the one for Chrome. Anyone knows where to post a bug report for that?